# How to pass django user authentication data to react app?

Tags: html, django, reactjs, authentication, request

I am doing a project by using `django` as front and back-end. But recently I want to attach another `react` page on this project. So, what I want to do is passing the user's info and mounting inside react. Below is my `django`'s structure, I bundled my react app and put it on `django`'s front-end (inside a toolbar). Normally, in django front-end, using `request.user` can get user's `auth` data. But how can I pass it to my react page? Thanks in advance!

```
**urls.py:**
url(r'test/', TestView, name='TestView')

**views.py**
def TestView(request):
    template_name = 'test.html'
    context = {}
    return render(request, template_name, context)

**test.html:**
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root" style="height:100%"></div>
        <script src="../../../test_bundle.js"></script>

</html>

**main_html.py:**
<div class="item">
    <div class="ui dropdown" id="test">
        <a class="item" onclick="load_test();">Test Component</a>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function load_test() {
        div_reload('#test', '/test/', 'GET', 'html');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this myself.

```
<script> let DjangoVars = {{ Status|safe }}; </script>
```

the above worked for me.

You have no variable defined in your context, but you would make a dictionary where the variable name is the key, which in this example is status.

I also had to define the variable in a string, within a string.

```
context = {"Status": f"'{logged_in}'"}
return render(request, "build/index.html", context)
```

I found this to be the easiest way to get around type errors.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update, what I ended up doing was adding a join response page to check if the user would be logged in or not. And then I would post to the login page and return an error response or a 200 if he authenticated.  I used react routes to switch the page if the check_login was true or false